# Vertically aligning components of a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, vertical-alignment

I have two views - a TextView and an ImageView - inside my relative layout. These are the outcome I would like:

1) if the imageview is hidden (it can be set to visibility=gone programatically if certain conditions are met), the textview is vertically and horizontally centre aligned in the relative layout

2) if the imageview is not hidden, the textview should be horizontally centre aligned but vertically take up no more space than it needs to - with the imageview taking up all available height.

This is the code I'm using. It is not working though, because if I set the imageview to fill_parent it overlaps the text and if I set it to wrap_content it is far too small:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout_buttons">

<TextView
       android:id="@+id/text_compliance_question"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:textSize="22sp"
       android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
       android:layout_above="@+id/image_thumbnail"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
       android:visibility="visible"
       android:id="@+id/image_thumbnail"
       android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to using a RelativeLayout? LinearLayout with weightSum might meet your need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is no particular reason for using RelativeLayout. If I use weights, won't it become a percentage game though? I don't need it done by percentage, I just want things to take up as much space as they can.

Comment: Using weight does not necessarily mean it is done by percentage. Set the weightSum to be "1" and the weight of ImageView's weight to be "1", the ImageView will just take as much space as it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your layout hope this is what you are looking for

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_margin="20dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="hello there"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
                android:text="dynamic button 1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
                android:text="dynamic button 2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
                android:text="dynamic button 3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
                android:text="dynamic button 2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="dynamic button 3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect, the change to a linear layout did the track! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using the following layout file might solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_compliance_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Hello world!" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_thumbnail"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/device_type_windows" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And when the image view is visiable/gone, it looks like:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. This is close to what I want, but how do I get it so the actual image takes up more space? For example, that Windows logo could probably grow to about 4 times the size shown? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite get your problem. You mean your image is 4 times larger than the windows logo or larger than the screen? As shown in the answer, all the space can be used for the image, i.e., the blue rectangle's height and the screen's width.

Comment: see the new picture, just change the layout_width of imageView's src to fill_parent.